# Using AndroidInjections contribution module (abstract class) as subcomponent in Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I study Dagger 2 and try to understand how I can attach it to an already existing project. Now I faced with the following problem with injectiing dependencies into `BroadcastReceivers`. I can't use `DaggerReceiver` because my receivers already extends another class. To use `AndroidInjection` inside `BroadcastReceivers`, I should inject `DispatchingAndroidInjector` to `Application` class. I don't want to include module with `AndroidInjection` contributors to main dependency graph so, how I understand, I should place it to dedicated component for `Application` class, but because of this duplication of Singletons occurs.

Here is my example ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/fishb1/Dagger2AndroidInjectorExample))

**Classes to provide dependencies to `MainActivity` and other classes**

*AppModule.class*

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Application providesApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

*UtilityModule.class*

```
@Module
public class UtilityModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    FirstUtilityClass providesFirstUtility(Application app) {
        return new FirstUtilityClass(app);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    SecondUtilityClass providesSecondUtility(Application app) {
        return new SecondUtilityClass(app);
    }
}
```

*MainComponent.class*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, UtilityModule.class })
public interface MainComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

**Classes to provide `DispatchingAndroidInjector` to `Application` class**

*ReceiversModule.class*

```
@Module
public abstract class ReceiversModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract FirstReceiver contributesFirstReceiver();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract SecondReceiver contributesSecondReceiver();
}
```

*ReceiversComponent.class*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, UtilityModule.class, ReceiversModule.class })
public interface ReceiversComponent {

    void inject(MyApplication application);
}
```

**Injecting...**

*MyApplication.class*

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements HasBroadcastReceiverInjector {

    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> mInjector;
    @Inject FirstUtilityClass mFirstUtility;
    @Inject SecondUtilityClass mSecondUtility;
    MainComponent mMainComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        AppModule appModule = new AppModule(this);
        mMainComponent = DaggerMainComponent.builder().appModule(appModule).build();
        // I should build new component only for Application class, because DispatchingAndroidInjector not required for another targets
        DaggerReceiversComponent.builder().appModule(appModule).build().inject(this); // Here created new scope
        super.onCreate();
        // do something
        mFirstUtility.doFistThings(getClass().getSimpleName());
        mSecondUtility.doSecondThings(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    public MainComponent getMainComponent() {
        return mMainComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverInjector() {
        return mInjector;
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.class*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject FirstUtilityClass mFirstUtility;
    @Inject SecondUtilityClass mSecondUtility;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getMainComponent().inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Do something
        mFirstUtility.doFistThings(getClass().getSimpleName());
        mSecondUtility.doSecondThings(getClass().getSimpleName());
        // Sending broadcasts here
    }
}
```

*Logcat output*

> FirstUtilityClass1: doing first things from MyApplication...
>
> SecondUtilityClass1: doing second things from MyApplication...
>
> FirstUtilityClass2: doing first things from MainActivity...
>
> SecondUtilityClass2: doing second things from MainActivity...
>
> FirstUtilityClass1: doing first things from FirstReceiver...
>
> SecondUtilityClass1: doing second things from SecondReceiver...

How you see in log, `Apllication` and `MainActivity` receives different instances of utility classes. I had an idea to make `ReceiversComponent` as a subcomponent of `MainComponent`. But `ReceiversModule` is abstract and I cant add it dinamicaly to existed component instance.

*MainComponent.class*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, UtilityModule.class })
public interface MainComponent {

    ReceiversComponent with(ReceiversModule module);

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

*ReceiversComponent.class*

```
@Subcomponent(modules = { ReceiversModule.class })
public interface ReceiversComponent {

    void inject(MyApplication application);
}
```

And then in `MyApplication`:

```
// It does not work because I can't create ReceiverModule instance :(
mMainComponent.with(new ReceiversModule()).inject(this);
```

How can I use the `ReceiversComponent` as a subcomponent of `MainComponent`?
It's clear to me that I'm doing something wrong, but I just can't understand where. Maybe there is another way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer!

Since my `ReceiversModule` class has a default constructor without parameters, I can skip it as parameter when describing the subcomponent in `MainComponent` interface:

*MainComponent.class*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, UtilityModule.class })
public interface MainComponent {

    ReceiversComponent withReceiversModule(); // Here is the reference to the subcomponent with abstract module

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

*MyApplication.class*

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    AppModule appModule = new AppModule(this);
    mMainComponent = DaggerMainComponent.builder().appModule(appModule).build();
    mMainComponent.withReceiversModule().inject(this); // It's works!!! :)
    super.onCreate();  
    // do something
    mFirstUtility.doFistThings(getClass().getSimpleName());
    mSecondUtility.doSecondThings(getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Maybe someone will think it is a trifle, but it took me several days to reach it. I'm very happy, because my code has become a little cleaner. Thanks to all!